# What's the benefit of cranked wing for commercial airplanes

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, commercial-aviation

Many commercial airplanes have a kink in the wing geometry.

[image]

A discontinuous change in the wing trailing edge sweep is present in the wing of the A320. What's the benefit of this? Is there any aerodynamic advantage?

Comment: Also [What is the purpose of a wing Yehudi?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42913/14897) BTW that's not a 737, that's an A320.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It may be very useful to study the Handley Page Victor.  Many of today's issues, such as tail requirement, critical Mach number, placement of jet engines, and drag reduction were addressed with this ungainly, but very practical aircraft.  They "repeatedly refueled" the delta Vulcans on long range missions.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Thanks for the reference! I will surely look into it.