# What is the average pitch of a plane?

Tags: aircraft-physics, pitch

I'm looking for the average pitch of big planes like an Airbus A300. For horizontal travel, is the plane horizontal or does it have a pitch like 1 or 2° (or more)?

If the plane does not accelerate and has a constant speed, is the gravity of the passengers a little backwards?

Comment: Does [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2726/62) help?

Comment: @Pondlife I think the OP is looking for hard values in degrees.

Comment: Good question. How to get an answer: put your iphone on the floor and use the level app. Turn the phone around and take the average.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "middle pitch" you're talking about the pitch during cruse? In which case, the answer is, unfortunately, "it depends". Changing pitch changes the amount of lift, and the amount of lift needed depends on the weight of the plane. So, an airplane with more passengers and cargo will need a slightly higher pitch.

Changing speed also changes lift, which will need to be compensated for by changing pitch. However, we're talking about cruise flight here, so speed will remain relatively constant.

Comment: You may improve your answer by adding lower and upper bounds (in degrees)

Answer (score 2):

At maximum cruise speed, altitude and payload, most airliners are trimmed into several degrees of pitch-up attitude to maintain constant altitude. At that point, the plane is delicately balanced at those conditions to minimize drag and maximize range.

Comment: I think you don't answer the question. The OP is looking for a pitch value and seems aware of cruise pitch attitude.

Comment: In the first link of Pondlife, someone said nose-up deck angle is about 2° (0° for fighters and 4° for jets). It’s the kind of aswer I’m looking for. Remember I’m talking about big planes like Airbus with normal charge and not the angle of wings but really the angle of plane with horizontal. Thanks for help :)

Comment: IME, at max speed in a Boeing jet (probably not all, but 1 of them), it's about 0-1 deg nose up (as read on the ADI) and at loiter speed at altitude it's about 5 degrees.